# Meaning of 離れている間 and how do I read it, please?

Tags: translation, readings, japanese-to-english

I'm reading a japanese manga and the boy didn't want to get away from his senpai, he told senpai that and senpai thought was having a monologue "離れている間".

Thankyou for taking your time reading this.

Comment: This board isn't for translation requests. What do you think it might mean? Even a guess is fine! And what's the rest of the sentence for context?

Comment: sorry about that, here's the rest of the text in the same bubble
"離れている間
ずっと不安だったけどかくしてたのか"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that means 'While I'm away'.

Not 100% sure. You should give the whole sentence.

離れている間 is pronounced 'Hanareteiru aida'.

Comment: sorry, here's the rest of the text in the bubble:
"離れている間ずっと不安だったけどかくしてたのか"
in google it translated as"Hanarete iru ma"
but at the same time it was pronounced as "Hanareteiru aida" with the voice but I got confused

Comment: yes, it was "While I was away" I thought it was "the moment of departure" but it wasn't thankyou!

Comment: 'Hanarete iru ma' is obviously wrong.

Leaning a language is always hard. Keep it up. It will pay off.